# SQL select with listing based on selected values

Tags: sql, select

I had a hard time coming up with a title, so I hope this is somewhat understandable...

I have the following table:

```
items:  id|name|...|visibleItems
```

E.g. it contains:

```
 1|test1|...|2
 2|test2|...|1
 3|test3|...|2
```

This is then joined with another table (customers) and I would like to list it as follows:

```
 cust1|test1|...
 cust2|test1|...
 cust3|test2|...
 cust4|test3|...
 cust4|test3|...
```

...thus using the 'visibleItems' as the number for items listed.

The SQL I have is something simple like:

```
SELECT [values] FROM [tables] WHERE [statements] ORDER BY name
```

Does this make sense? If so, what to do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a customer_id foreign key in the items table? If so, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT customers.name AS customer_name, item.name AS item_name FROM customers
INNER JOIN items ON items.customer_id=customers.id;
```

`visibleItems` wouldn't control how many customers are listed per item--the foreign key relationship and join would do that.

See here for a decent explanation of the various join types: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: I do not have a foreign key on 'visibleItems'... Guess I'll have to do that then...